# Add Function in doubly linked list results in infinite loop

Tags: c++, linked-list, infinite-loop, traversal, nullptr

I've been having trouble programming a doubly linked list. The problem is that my Add function results in an infinite loop when I check if the links are nullptr. When I don't, it gives me an error. I've been trying to fix this and for the life of me can't figure it out. Below is the add method:

```
    void Add(string n, int w) //Method to add a node to the Linked List and maintain the order.
{

    node * nd = new node(n, w, nullptr, nullptr);

    if (nHead == nullptr && wHead == nullptr) //If there is nothing in the Linked List
    {
        nHead = nd; //Add a node
        wHead = nd;
    }

    else //If there is something in the linked List
    {
        node * ntraverse = nHead; //variable to traverse down the name links

        while (nd->name > ntraverse->name && ntraverse->wLink != nullptr)
        {
            ntraverse = ntraverse->nLink; // Traverses down the name links until nd's name is smaller than a links
        }

        nd->nLink = ntraverse; // Here, the namelink for nd is set to ntraverse, since ntraverse is less than or equal to nlink
        ntraverse->nLink = nd; // So here, since nd is the new value appended to the rest of the list, we set ntraverse = nlink.

                               // note at this point, we have not handled weight

        node * wtraverse = wHead; //variable to traverse down the weight links

        while (nd->weight > wtraverse->weight && wtraverse->wLink != nullptr)
        {
            wtraverse = wtraverse->wLink; // Traverses down the weight links until nd's weight is smaller than a links
        }

        nd->wLink = wtraverse; // Here, the namelink for nd is set to ntraverse, since ntraverse is less than or equal to nlink
        wtraverse->wLink = nd; // So here, since nd is the new value appended to the rest of the list, we set ntraverse = nlink.

        //at this point, nd holds both the correct nlink and wlink

    }

    cout << "Added: " << nd->name << " " << nd->weight << "\n";
    cout << "Current nlist:\n";
    nPrint();
    cout << "Current wlist:\n";
    wPrint();

    size++; //increment size

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. If you need me to answer anything, please let me know. Node works fine, it stores 4 values: name, weight, nLink, and wLink, where nLink keeps the list ordered by name and wLink keeps the list ordered by weight. For LinkedList, nHead is the name head and wHead is the weight head.

Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: I assume this is "C" or "C++"? Please add the appropriate tags. If so, what is `nullptr`

Comment: C++, The reason why I added nullptr is that I thought that something may be going wrong when checking the links for nullptr.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing you wLink and nLink together

```
node * ntraverse = nHead; //variable to traverse down the name links

while (nd->name > ntraverse->name && ntraverse->wLink != nullptr)
```

In the above you are traversing the name links and testing to see if you are at the end of the weight list.

This isn't a doubly linked list, it is two singly linked lists and you should treat each list separately.

In other words your code should look something like this:

```
    void Add(string n, int w) //Method to add a node to the Linked List and maintain the order.
{

    node * nd = new node(n, w, nullptr, nullptr);

    if (nHead == nullptr ) //If there is nothing in the Linked List
    {
        nHead = nd; //Add a node
    }


    else //If there is something in the linked List
    {
       /* Code to handle nLink with no mention of wLink */
    }

    if (wHead == nullptr ) //If there is nothing in the Linked List
    {
        wHead = nd; //Add a node
    }


    else //If there is something in the linked List
    {
       /* Code to handle wLink with no mention of nLink */
    }

}
```

Of course, the ideal solution would be to write a linked list class....

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your answer. First of all, this is a method inside the Linked List class. First, when I changed `while (nd->name > ntraverse->name && ntraverse->wLink != nullptr)` to `while (nd->name > ntraverse->name && ntraverse->nLink != nullptr)` it still results in an infinite loop. Second, this is a doubly linked list. Node has four values, Name, Weight, nLink, and wLink, where nLink points to the next node ordered by name and wLink points to the next node ordered by weight, hence why I do not separate the if statement.

Comment: In a doubly linked list  each node would have a pointer to the next node and a pointer to the previous node. This means that the following is true (except for the end nodes): ` n->Next->Prev == n` You have a singly linked list of names and a singly linked list of weights

Comment: The definition of a doubly linked node is simply that it has two links. It does not necessarily have to have a forward link and a back link, although that is how it is conventionally used. In this case, the node stores 2 links, both being ordered by different variables.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what the problem was. At the end of each loop, I had

```
    nd->wLink = wtraverse; // Here, the namelink for nd is set to ntraverse, since ntraverse is less than or equal to nlink
    wtraverse->wLink = nd; // So here, since nd is the new value appended to the rest of the list, we set ntraverse = nlink.
```

This was creating a circular loop. nd's link stored wtraverse, and wtraverse's link stored nd, meaning that one of the links would point back to another part of the list.

As for the semantic argument over the Doubly Linked List terminology, my professor in Data Structures refers to a data structure where the node has two links as a Doubly Linked List. Whether it is correct or not, arguing semantics was of little help and did not do anything to fix the problem.